# How to find a parametrization for a torus?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, manifolds

I need to compute the surface area of the torus $$T^2=\{(x,y,z)\subseteq\mathbb R^3 \left(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}- R\right)^2+z^2=r^2\}$$
where $0<r<R$.

I know I need to compute the metric tensor and the Gramian determinant etc, but in order to so, I need a regular global parametrization of $T^2$, I guess? How do obtain the latter for such a set?

Some help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use Pappus's centroid theorem?

Comment: Haven't dealt with that in lecture yet

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy derivation of the surface area of a torus (without using metric tensor or the Gramian determinant).

All we have to do is compute the following integral:

$$2\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(R+r\cos\theta\right)\cdot rd\theta$$

Which can be explained through this diagram:
[image]

Since $\displaystyle \int(R+r\cos\theta)\cdot rd\theta=r\left(r\sin(\theta)+R\theta\right)+C$ , we conclude that

$$\displaystyle2\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(R+r\cos\theta\right)\cdot rd\theta=4\pi^2Rr$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am really bad at geometric interpretation

Answer (score 1):

We can describe the surface of the torus using parameters $(\phi,\alpha)$ by the position vector $\vec r(\phi,\alpha)$

$$\begin{align}
\vec r(\phi,\alpha)&=\hat \rho(\phi) R+(\hat \rho(\phi) r\cos(\alpha)+\hat z r\sin(\alpha))\\\\
&=\hat \rho(\phi)\,(R+r\cos(\alpha))+\hat z r\sin(\alpha)
\end{align}$$

where $\hat \rho(\phi)=\hat x \cos(\phi)+\hat y \sin(\phi)$ is the radial unit vector in cylindrical coordinates, $0\le \phi<2\pi$, and $0\le \alpha<2\pi$.

Note that the angle $\alpha$ can be interpreted as the polar angle in a local cylindrical coordinate system centered at points on the axis of the torus.

Answer (score 1):

Note you have a sum of squares equal a constant. Hence you should use trigonometric functions.
$$
\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R\right)^2+z^2=r^2
$$
So we set $z=r\cos(\phi),\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R=r\sin(\phi)$. Squaring the second relation we get
$$
x^2+y^2=(R+r\sin(\phi))^2
$$
So we may introduce another angle an set $x=(R+r\sin(\phi))\cos(\theta),y=(R+r\sin(\phi))\sin(\theta)$. And this gives you the natural parametrization of the torus (You can see for ur self that those angles actually have a geometric meaning)
$$
x=(R+r\cos(\phi))\cos(\theta)\\
y=(R+r\sin(\phi))\sin(\theta)\\
z=r\cos(\phi)
$$

Comment: Typo in z  should be cos $ \phi$

Comment: Thanks alot. But where do the factors $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ come from?

Comment: From the equation $x^2+y^2=(R+r*sin(\phi))^2$ you get that for every fixed $\phi$ you get a circle on the $xy$ plane. From where those angles appear